# Azure DevOps - Setting An Environment Variable on the Target Machine in a Deploy Group

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I am deploying an Asp.Net Core application via Azure DevOps' Pipelines option and trying to set an environment variable on each of the target machines. Each deployment environment has its own settings file (for example "appsettings.Development.json") that the Asp.Net app chooses from when it starts up by reading the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable. I am using a Deploy Group to deploy the artifact to our on-site servers and that is working perfectly until it comes to setting the correct appsettings file to use.

I tried unsuccessfully to use a PowerShell task that has this inline script:

`$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="$(EnvironmentName)"`

All the pipeline tasks are executed successfully but the environment variable doesn't actually get applied on the target machine.

How can I set an environment variable on the target machines in a Deploy Group?

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me know if there is any issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The above inline script of yours `$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="$(EnvironmentName)"` only set the variable in the current terminal window opened by the powershell task. The terminal window will be shut down after the powershell task  is complete. We usually use below solutions to set environment variables in the pipeline.

If you want to set an environment variable on the target machines in the release pipeline. You can directly set a variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in the release pipeline **Variables** tab. See below:

Go to your release **Edit** page-->**Variables** tab-->**Add** new Variable-->Set the stage **Scope**

[image]

There is another way to set the environment variables dynamically using [logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable)(`Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable..]`) in the pipeline. See below inline script in powershell task:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT]$(EnvironmentName)"
```

Please check the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Setting an environment variable that way isn't persistent, as you've observed. You'll need to the .NET environment variable methods to accomplish what you want.

`[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT', '$(EnvironmentName)' [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)`